# Json Data Not Displaying in ListView

Tags: android, json, get, android-volley

I am Trying to parse Json data into a list view
The list view is declared, and the Url I use is built with Uri.Builder, I have tested the URL with POSTMAN and it works and displays the data(on PostMan)
I am Using Volley to get the data
I can not figure out what the problem is
The code I use works for populating other list views but as soon as I add more paramaters, It shows blank

My Json data

```
{"success": 1,"Name": [{"ProjectDescription": "Project Name"},{"TaskCode": "VAL001"},{"TasDescription": "Value text
test"}]}
```

My Code

```
  private void LoadTaskSpinner(String url) {
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(reportActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait..Loading Time Log Data");
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pd.show();
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                pd.cancel();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getInt("success") == 1) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Name");
                        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String task=jsonObject1.getString("ProjectDescription");
                            String code=jsonObject1.getString("TaskCode");
                            String desc=jsonObject1.getString("TasDescription");
                            Project.add(task);
                            Project.add(code);
                            Project.add(desc);
                        }
                    }
                    report.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(reportActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Project));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.cancel();

                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        int socketTimeout=30000;
        RetryPolicy policy=new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: are you getting response while calling API from app.?

Comment: No I don't call an API I am going to pull the data from my server, I am just using a simple GET from volley, to pull a file with the json data from my server

Comment: ok are you getting your data from server.?

Comment: Yes the data is in a file on my server,

Comment: Have you check edited code. If not then change these two lines  String key=jsonObject1.keys().next();
                            String task=jsonObject1.getString(key);. Above code will works.

Comment: LoadTaskSpinner("Example url") are you calling this method and getting response in 
onResponse(String response) .? or any Error in error method.?

Comment: The Code works for pulling other Json data from the same server, The problem only occurs when I add more paramaters

Comment: @ShivKumar Thanks Dude, I Saw And mentioned you in my answer,

Comment: @RubenMeiring check if key exist if (jsonObject1.has("ProjectDescription")) {task=jsonObject1.getString("ProjectDescription")} try adding has check you were getting null key thats why it was crashing or not displaying data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shiv Kumar, Suggested an Edit for me,
This Solved my Issue

```
  JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String key=jsonObject1.keys().next();
                        String task=jsonObject1.getString(key);
                        // String code=jsonObject1.getString("TaskCode");
                        // String desc=jsonObject1.getString("TasDescription");
                        Project.add(task);
                        //Project.add(code);
                        //Project.add(desc);
```

Comment: what if you are getting ProjectDescription key only.? you will map it to other object right.?

Answer (score -1):

check if strings != null && strings != "" then add to the project.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer please

Comment: in for loop when you get jsonObject(0) you dont have "TaskCode" and "TasDescription" , you can get only "ProjectDescription" text.

Comment: your json is very bad for parsing, if you can, change it

Comment: Json is for testing purposes only, So The JSON will be pulled from my server linked to a database

Comment: Yes, The thing is I can Pull the data with the same code, but as soon as I add more string params it comes as blank

Comment: your json should be like this                                                                                                                {"success": 1,"Name": [{"ProjectDescription": "Project Name" ,"TaskCode": "VAL001" , "TasDescription": "Value text
            test"},
            {"ProjectDescription": "Project Name2" ,"TaskCode": "VAL0012" , "TasDescription": "Value text
            test2"} ]}                                                                                                                           try to change your json structure

Comment: The Json is for Testing purposes only, The Json data will be dynamicly given from the serve

Comment: so change it from server :)